# What do you call a DAG with a single root/source?

Tags: graphs

What's the name for a DAG (directed acyclic graph) that has a unique *root* or *source* node from which every other node can be reached?

Alternatively, if you change the direction of the arrows, what's the name for a DAG that has some unique *sink* node that is reachable from every other node?

Here's an example graph:

[image: example graph]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't a standard name for that, at least none I'm aware of. I've seen that structure being called "rooted DAG", by analogy with "rooted tree".

Answer (score 9):

In a directed graph we do not speak of roots and leaves, but of sources and sinks.

I'm not aware of any term that designates a DAG with only a single source, but you could just call it that: "a DAG with a single source".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and I've updated my question to say *source* and *sink* as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you think of the DAG as a graph whose reachability relation is a partial order relation, then an element with that property would be a minimum element in that relation.

I haven't seen the term "minimum element" used this way before, but I suspect that someone seeing that notation would likely be able to understand it if you included a quick explanatory sentence.

Comment: I support this view. See [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram).