# What is the name of a rooted tree whose nodes may have edges to their descendants?

Tags: graphs, data-structures, trees, graph-traversal, dag

A tree is a special kind a graph.

However, I came across a data structure which is a like a rooted tree, but where nodes are authorized to have direct links to any of their descendants. Shortcuts if you will.

This is not a tree anymore.

This is a specialized DAG that has more restriction. That is, it has a single root (or source)

Does this type of graph have a name?

CLARIFICATION:

By 'tree', I'm referring to the [tree data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)), not a [tree in graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)). It seems crazy to me that such related objects have the same name even though they don't mean the same thing.
The tree data structure is always rooted but there are rooted DAG that are not trees.

{1→2, 2→3, 1→3, 4→2} doesn't qualify because 4→2 is an edge toward an ancestor, not a descendant.
{1→2, 1→3, 2→4, 3→4} doesn't qualify.

{1→2, 2→3, 1→3} and {1→2, 1→3, 2→4, 3→5, 3→6, 1→4, 1→6} both qualify.

Comment: Let $G$ be the graph on $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and edges $\{1\to2,\  2\to3,\  1\to3,\  4\to2\}$. Is $G$ an example of the graphs you are talking about? Note that $G$ has two sources (or roots).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do you call a DAG with a single root/source?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67849/what-do-you-call-a-dag-with-a-single-root-source)

Comment: @PålGD No, it's more restrictive than a single-sourced DAG and this isn't a duplicate. The graph shown in the question you've linked is _not_ in the class Clement is interested in.

Comment: @Apass.Jack, I clarified the question. G doesn't qualify because of 4→2.

Comment: OK, I am glad you have clarified you are talking tree data structure. However, it looks like you have conflicting description when you said "which is a like a rooted tree, but where nodes are authorized to have direct links to any of their descendants" and that you believe "{1→2, 1→3, 2→4, 3→4} " qualifies. Please check my answer.

Comment: The two kinds of trees have the same name because they're the same thing. A tree in the sense of data structures is just (an implementation of) a tree in the sense of directed graphs, in which every edge points away from the root. And, um, you tagged the question "graphs" "graph-traversal" "DAG" but not "data-structures", which seemed to say pretty explicitly that you were thinking graph theoretically.

Comment: @Apass.Jack you're right, the example you point out doesn't qualify. I fixed the question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I agree both objects are a type of tree and share that in common but it is precisely because they are almost the same but not quite the same that they should have a slightly different name, like directed graph and directed acyclic graph are almost the same but have a different name. Maybe they should be 'tree' and 'strict tree' or some other adjective to point out the data structure tree is more specialized.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I added the data-structures tag. The reason I tagged with graph is because one of the two types of trees is a graph.

Comment: No, a tree data structure really is just an implementation of a tree graph. Context almost always disambiguates. Adding the condition "acyclic" is a genuine restriction to the class of directed graphs. (Or have I misunderstood you? If you mean that the relationship between your trees-with-extra-links and an ordinary tree is somewhat similar to the relationship between directed graphs and DAGs, then I agree.)

Comment: Yes it is what I mean, a tree data structure is more restrictive than a tree graph. It is the first time I come across trees in the context of graphs and it was definitely ambiguous hence why I had to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer does not have a suggestion as to what existing names we might have. Rather, it is about what names are not appropriate.

To be clear, the OP talks about a graph that is a rooted tree with possibly extra edges from some nodes to its descendants. Let us call this kind of graph "Clement directed acycle graph" or, in short, "**Clement DAG**" for the lack of a better concise name (Clement is the OP's username).

The simplest example of Clement DAG that is not a tree is a graph on vertices $\{1,2,3\}$ with edges $\{1\to 2,\ 2\to 3,\ 1\to 3\}$.

One might be tempted to think "a Clement DAG" is none other than "a rooted directed acycle graph"(**rooted DAG**) or, what is equivalent, "a directed acyclic graph with a single source". Indeed, **a Clement DAG is always a rooted DAG. However, a rooted DAG is not necessarily a Clement DAG**! Here is an example given by David Richerby. Let $G$ be a graph vertices $\{1,2,3,4\}$ with edges $\{1\to 2,\ 1\to 3,\ 2\to 4,\ 3\to 4\}$. $G$ has a single root, $1$. If $G$ is a Clement DAG, $G$ must be a tree since it has no extra edge that connects any node to its descendants others than its children. However, $G$ has a cycle.

Comment: So I guess there is no official name for it yet. I hope that "Clement DAG" sticks :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any standard term. The graphs that you describe are subgraphs of the transitive closure of a tree, if that's of any help to you, but one wouldn't want to use that phrase twenty times in a paper.

But... as [Pål GD](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/4249/p%c3%a5l-gd) alludes to in [a comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/96456/what-is-the-name-of-a-rooted-tree-whose-nodes-may-have-edges-to-their-descendant/96466?noredirect=1#comment205509_96466), *every* DAG on $n$ vertices is a subgraph of the transitive closure of the $n$-vertex directed path. So this answer is a bit of a fail, really.

Comment: Then again ... every graph is (isomorphic to) a subgraph of a transitive closure of a tree.

Comment: @PålGD Well, "directed" was strongly implicit... so it's only every DAG. But, still, oops.